# Display rows only if two columns in an CSV are unique

Tags: excel, csv

I have an csv file and want only rows having unique values in A and B to be displayed in the excel file. Should be unique in A and B.

```
Id |Version | Program Name
  1      9         SF
  2      9         DF
  1      9         DF
  1      8         SF

Output:
Id| Version | Program Name
 1     9           SF
 2     9           DF
 1     8           DF
```

Is there a formula that I can apply to get the desired output?

Comment: Could use the Remove Duplicates feature in Excel, or if you need to preserve the data you can copy it into a new excel file (or just a new sheet) and then do the remove duplicates.

Comment: Given the same ID and Version (A and B), how do you know one program (C) takes precedence over the other? Are you sure there is not more to the requirements than just keep the first occurrence of A and B?

Comment: @Gary_W Yes, your concern is valid. However, I was only focusing on the result where the rows with (C1 AND C2) are same are returned. Thank you.

Comment: @tigeravatar remove duplicates worked. thank you!